# C# WebBrowser control - creating and modifying a javascript variable using DOM then reading it using Applet

Tags: c#, javascript, dom, applet, browser

I need to make a communication process between java applet and C# WebBrowser control's html page. And I want to do it without refreshing the html page. I know I can communicate with applet using applet parameters, but in that case I have to refresh everytime the applet page to get updated parameter. I also can use cookie, but I dont want to send all those unnecessary cookies to server for each request. So I was thinking if there is a way to create javacript array variable using DOM and then read it with the applet. But I dont know if it is possible or may be there are other ways to do it. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please can tell me me what options are you after of the WebBrowser Control

Comment: @HatSoft: I just want to communicate with applet. And want to send some values into it. I am using C# WebBrowser control. But I have to send those values from html (I dont have other choice). So I am looking for a easy option to do it.

Comment: So all you want to do is embbed your java applet with params in WebBrowser Control?

Comment: @HatSoft: Well I can do that. But if I need to pass new params then I cant do it without refreshing whole page. Because as I know applet fetch all the params at the initialization time (not sure though). But the main problem is that this applet is quite big and take too much time to load, so I dont want to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by injecting html code in the Webrowser Controls **DocumentText** property

```
string htmlCode = "<html><head></head><body>";
htmlCode += "<applet code="Example.class" width="350" height="350"></applet>";
htmlCode +="</body></html>";

webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlCode;
```